# has multiple clauses and defines defaults in one or more clauses

Tags: elixir

I have a function confirm_user, which can be called with the argument `%User{}` or `nil`.

```
def confirm_user(%User{} = user, attrs \\ %{}) do
    Repo.update(User.confirm_changeset(user, attrs))
end

def confirm_user(nil, attrs \\ %{}) do
    {:error, :not_found}
end
```

But with this definition I get an error:

```
def confirm_user/2 has multiple clauses and defines defaults in one or more clauses
```

why? Is `%User{} = user` and nil not pattern matching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare above all one head that sets default arguments:

```
def confirm_user(_user, attr \\ %{})
def confirm_user(%User{} = user, attrs) do
  user
  |> User.confirm_changeset(attrs)
  |> Repo.update() 
end

def confirm_user(nil, attrs) do
  {:error, :not_found}
end
```

You could also use a bit more explicit approach and declare `confirm_user/1` on your own - this is what actually the `\\` operator is doing.

```
def confirm_user(user) do
  confirm_user(user, %{}) # call confirm_user/2 when no attrs are provided
end

def confirm_user(%User{} = user, attrs) do
  user
  |> User.confirm_changeset(attrs)
  |> Repo.update() 
end

def confirm_user(nil, attrs) do
  {:error, :not_found}
end
```

`%User{} = user` help you to get the whole struct as the `user` thanks to the pattern matching, so you don't need to assign in the function block.

Edit:

[Here's the exact comment](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/src/elixir_def.erl#L362) with explanation how your code should looks like.